# Store a value with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've got a Rails app where I need salaries to be paid every month for instance. So I need to store the last time the salaries where paid somewhere.

I don't want to use database because I don't want to create a table just for that, I think it doesn't make much sense. I've thought of writing it to the cache but I don't know if the data is secured and can't be lost.

Has someone got an idea of a place where I can store this time ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the `salaryPaid` variable to the `employee` model, and update it each time you pay the salary (or whatever is equivalent for your app). This would still use a database but it would just make a new entry for each employee and would be easy to manage with migrations.

Comment: The problem with this is that I have only one date repeated many many times... I'd like to store it once !